# .NET command line tool hosed my environment, please help

Tags: .net, wcf

I've been having problems with WCF all day. Now, I'm afraid I hosed my dev environment. I'm hoping somebody can help me otherwise I'm going to have to repave :(.

In an effort to solve a WCF problem I was having, I following the recommendation in the last post of this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsprereleaseannouncements/thread/44dfcf76-bede-4f96-a556-b219a18b6116

That recommendation says to run:

```
ServiceModelReg.exe -r
```

I did that. Now, when I attempt to do anything webrelated on my machine I see the following error message:
*Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

I have .NET 4.0 installed and I ran the executable that was in the 3.0 directory :(. Is there anyway I can reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

In the %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config folder are a number of `.default` files; these are vanilla "as shipped" 4.0 files, so it should be OK to drop those over the non-.default ones. But take a copy of the ones you replace *as well*, in case you're not on the right track - as this will essentially uninstall any changes you have made to your main configs.

Also; are you sure that your "webrelated" code is running 4.0? it might still be ASP.NET 2.0 with .NET 3.5SP1 (which includes a 3.0 service pack) - maybe you've only reverted to the vanilla 3.0 / 3.5 code? Hard to tell from here.